# Does Azure B2C User Flows support SAML protocol?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml, spring-saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Using Azure B2C User Flows is it possible to configure clients with SAML protocol support? Or for is required to use Custom Policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-user-flow). "This feature is available only for custom policies".